# How I can use JQuery image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble putting together my jQuery image slider. I have no idea what is wrong with it. I'm using `responsiveslides.js` (http://responsiveslides.com/)`

```css
/* RESET */

html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, a, article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section {
  /* Cancel out some differences between browser defaults */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

* {
  /* Padding and borders will be subtracted from the content box width, not added to it. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, aside, audio, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section {
  /* Make sure the browser knows how to display HTML5 elements */
  display: block;
}

header img{
  display: block;
  width: 30em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#wrap{
  background-image: url(Images\seamless-old-style-wallpaper-Download-Royalty-free-Vector-File-EPS-37757.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px;
}
nav {
    width: 40em;
    height: 3em;
    background: light grey;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: white;
  }

nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: calc(40em / 6);

}



nav ul li a, nav ul li a :visited  {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #white;
}

nav ul li a: hover {
  color: brown;
}
li a { text-decoration: none; color:#fff; }
li a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#fff; }
li a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#512e15; }
li a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#fff; }
li a:hover, li a:active { text-decoration: none; color:#512e15; }

footer{
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 40em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: light grey;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  clear: left;
}

p, address, #phone, #email{
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: .75em;
}
footer img{
  height:1em;
  width: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;


}
body{
  display: flex;
}

#leftSide{
  float:left;
  width: 32em;
  height: 16.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 7em;
  margin-right:7em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
aside{
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
#title h1{
  color: white;
margin-top: .25em;
margin-bottom: .25em
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;

}
iframe{
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Great Art</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body background="Images\flock_wallpaper_pattern_by_hydrogen666.jpg">
<div id=wrap>
    <header>
        <img src="Images\Great Art logo 2.jpg" alt="Great Art Logo"> </img>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="artist biography.html">artist biography</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">blog page</a></li>
            <li><a href="about us.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact us.html">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id=main>
        <ul class="rslides">
            <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p> Great Art </p>
        <address> PO Box 12-345 Christchurch </address>
        <p id=phone> Phone: 03 345 6789 </p>
        <p id=email> Email: hubert@great-art.org.nz </p>
        <img src="Images\fb-art.jpg"> <img src="Images\twitter logo.png">
    </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have inserted the .js into the containing folder, I can't think of why it won't run.

Comment: try to add this script at head section  <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>

Comment: still doesnt move, just stays as one solid image

Comment: Slider is working ..but where are trying to place the slider..as it currently used in footer and you need to scroll down to see the slider..created codepen URL for reference - http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: can you please explain why it is in the footer div?

Answer (score 0):

You should have hte id in quotes and you are not closing off the div that houses it until after the scrip block. you should move the script block out of the div and to the bottom of the page and then you will close the divb and it should work.- it should be:

```
     <div id= "main">
        <ul class="rslides">
          <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
//other code
<script>//code//</script>
```

also you are closing your img tags incorrectly - and using backward slashed when htey should for forward slashes: it should be

```
    <img src= "Images/fb-art.jpg" alt="facebook logo"/>
    <img src= "Images/twitter logo.png" alt="twitter logo"/>
```

Comment: Fixed all these, thank you. but it still wont work. :(

Comment: it seems as if you have the div #wrap around all the page elements - this might present an issue with the background image you are applying to it. Try removing the slider div out of wrap and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

1. i tested on official js(i advice u to replace it in your html head too)

> ```
> <!-- //official jquery -->
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <!-- //official responsiveslides -->
> <script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js?v=1.6"></script>
> ```

2. Move main slidshow script trigger it in  (i add auto starter, mb that why in your code slideshow won't start X), without pagination, without navigation)

   $(function () {

   ```
     $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
       auto: true,
       pagination: false,
       nav: false,
       fade: 500
     });

   });
   ```